# How do I step into the Perl Script Line by line?

Tags: perl

i am very new to Perl scripting language and I am running a Perl script at the moment. Which runs fairly well. However, I want to debug the script so that I can step into the code at the run time and see the control moving line by line. As we can do in Visual Studio.

I did try

```
Perl -d My script.pl
```

But I do not think that is what I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, on the command line it is. There are a number of programs that let you do visual debugging. You could try [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/), the Perl editor. Or, if you like a Visual Studio-like IDE, either look at [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) (commercial) or [EPIC for Eclipse](http://www.epic-ide.org/).

I am using Komodo and like it a lot.

There also is a list of a few other tools on [perl.org](http://debugger.perl.org/tools.html).